# How to use ng-repeat for repeating row using a property inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two arrays expArr and usrArr. I want to repeat the whole table based on first array and the second table should be repeated row wise.

```
$scope.expArr = [
    {"competency":"Proficient", "Name":"course1"},
    {"competency":"Proficient", "Name":"course2"},
    {"competency":"Expert", "Name":"course3"},
    {"competency":"Intermediate", "Name":"course4"},
    {"competency":"Proficient", "Name":"course5"}
] ;

$scope.userArr = [
    {"Name": "name1", "Prof":"Expert,Profocient,Basic,Basic,Basic"},
    {"Name":"name2","Prof":"Expert,Profocient,Basic1,Basic1,Basic1"}
] ;
```

I want the table to contain corusename and proficiency and the next columns should be repeated based on the second array. So as a result each row will contain the coursename, proficiency and each user's proficiency(separate column for each user). How to achieve this.

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/keshav_1007/ygzo8yfg/5/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Course</th>
    <th>Expected Prof</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="comp in expArr track by $index">
    <td>{{comp.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{comp.competency}}</td>    
  </tr>
  </table>  
  <table class="otherTable">
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="elem in custArr">{{elem.Name}}</th>
  </tr>  
  </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.expArr = [
    {"competency":"Proficient", "Name":"course1"},
    {"competency":"Proficient", "Name":"course2"},
    {"competency":"Expert", "Name":"course3"},
    {"competency":"Intermediate", "Name":"course4"},
    {"competency":"Proficient", "Name":"course5"}
] ;

$scope.userArr = [
    {"Name": "name1", "Prof":"Expert,Profocient,Basic,Basic,Basic"},
    {"Name":"name2","Prof":"Expert,Profocient,Basic1,Basic1,Basic1"}
] ;

$scope.custArr = [];
angular.forEach($scope.userArr,function(item){
    var profs = item.Prof.split(',');
  $scope.custArr.push({"Name":item.Name,"userProf":profs});
  }); 
console.log($scope.custArr);
});
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate `tr` as per the length of the `userProfs`
- Iterate item from array using `index` of `tr`

Use `$parent.$index` to get iteration index of `parent`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.expArr = [{
    "competency": "Proficient",
    "Name": "course1"
  }, {
    "competency": "Proficient",
    "Name": "course2"
  }, {
    "competency": "Expert",
    "Name": "course3"
  }, {
    "competency": "Intermediate",
    "Name": "course4"
  }, {
    "competency": "Proficient",
    "Name": "course5"
  }];

  $scope.userArr = [{
    "Name": "name1",
    "Prof": "Expert,Profocient,Basic,Basic,Basic"
  }, {
    "Name": "name2",
    "Prof": "Expert,Profocient,Basic1,Basic1,Basic1"
  }];
  $scope.custArr = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.userArr, function(item) {
    var profs = item.Prof.split(',');
    $scope.custArr.push({
      "Name": item.Name,
      "userProf": profs
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.otherTable tr td,
.myTable tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.otherTable th,
.myTable th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.otherTable,
.myTable {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<h1>TTA</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table class="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th>Expected Prof</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="comp in expArr track by $index">
      <td>{{comp.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{comp.competency}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="otherTable">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="elem in custArr">{{elem.Name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="u in custArr[0].userProf track by $index">
      <td ng-repeat="key in custArr">{{key.userProf[$parent.$index]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ygzo8yfg/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split user prof in such a way that you can multiple users with multiple course names, please refer http://jsfiddle.net/ygzo8yfg/10/ running code of your problem.

Structure 2 dimensional array of courses/users

```
var profArr = $scope.userArr[0].Prof.split(',');
$scope.personArr = [];
$scope.suggestArr = [];
var rowArr = [];
angular.forEach($scope.userArr,function(item){
    $scope.personArr.push({"name":item.Name});
});

for(var idx=0;idx<profArr.length; idx++){
    rowArr = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.userArr,function(item){
    if(!item.profArr){
      item.profArr = item.Prof.split(',');
    }
    rowArr.push({"proff":item.profArr[idx]});
  }); 
  $scope.suggestArr.push(rowArr);
}
```

Then iterate those in your table, first row for person names and data should iterate proficiency.

```
<table class="otherTable">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="person in personArr">{{person.name}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="el in suggestArr">
      <td ng-repeat="elem in el">{{elem.proff}}</td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
```